# Get data from web depending on cell value (JSON)

Tags: json, excel

I can see here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbJcOL39H8s) how to get data from web, but how can I get data from web depending on a cell value.

For example: 'https://someurl.com/json?v=' + A$2

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1655684/925350) or [this site](https://www.conradakunga.com/blog/consuming-rest-json-apis-from-excel/)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer:
https://exceltown.com/en/tutorials/power-bi/power-query-m-language/value-from-excel-cell-directly-to-power-query/

Everything is well explained.

So in Power Query:

```
var = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tableName"]}[Content][columnName],
Origem = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://someurl.com/file.php", [Query=[a=var{0}, a1=var{1}]])),
```

tableName: Is the name of the table you create;

columnName: Is the name of the column you create in that table.

Thank you all.